Dificuldades na verificação de valor com o Operador Ternário
Bem pessoal, estou iniciando no JavaScript e comecei a dar uma olhada no tal operador ternário.
Porém enquanto eu ia utilizando ele recentemente em um projeto, notei umas dificuldades quando coloco para verificar se dentro do Input possui algum valor.
A idéia do projeto é Gerar Números  Aleatórios de acordo com os valores máximo e mínimo colocado no input pelo usuário.

    let BtnResult = document.getElementById('BtnResultado')
    let MIN = document.getElementById('Min-Input')
    let MAX = document.getElementById('Max-Input')

    let Resulttext = document.getElementById('PText')

    BtnResult.addEventListener('click', function(){
    
    let maxValue = Number(MAX.value)
    let minValue = Number(MIN.value)
    let resultsArray = []

    !minValue || !maxValue ? (alert('Digite algo nas caixas'), console.log(undefined)) : 0;

    for(let i = minValue; i < maxValue; i++ ){
        const Rumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue + 1) + minValue)
        // Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min
        resultsArray.push(Rumber)
    }
    Resulttext.innerHTML = resultsArray.join(' || ' )
    // .join() -> ele escreve na tela todos os números inseridos na array.


    })

esse é o código completo, porém quando estou utilizando a estrutura If...Else, como no exemplo abaixo:
// if...else tradicional

 if (!minValue || !maxValue){
alert("digite algo")
}else{
alert("funcionou")
}


o segundo alert (alert("funcionou")), é disparado. Porque eu digitei um valor nos inputs, mesmo esse valor digitado sendo o número (0)


// Com ternário 

!minValue || !maxValue ? alert("digite algo") : alert('funcionou');

Porém quando eu passo a utilizar o operador ternário no meu código:
alert ("digite algo")

Esse alert() é disparado, mesmo eu digitando no input o número (0), e o restante do código funciona normalmente.
Porém o alert("digite algo") só precisa ser disparado quando realmente estiver sem nenhum valor nos inputs
Gostaria de saber pq isso acontece, explicando a diferença de cada um, e uma possível solução de qual seria a melhor opção para esse caso.

Se não me engano, vi essa pergunta hoje de manhã... lá havia um comentário para ajudar

A solução já foi dada na pergunta anterior (que foi apagada): https://jsfiddle.net/yv256urd/ - Dito isso, só vai entrar no else se os valores forem a string "0". Mas como no seu código vc usou Number para converter o value para número, então se um dos valores for zero, vai sempre entrar no if. Outro detalhe é que se não digitar nada, value será a string vazia, e Number converte para zero (pode testar aqui). Enfim, no primeiro link tem a solução: usar parseInt e testar se retornou NaN, assim ele já trata o caso que não preencheu, etc

Por fim, se quer testar explicitamente pelo valor zero, seria melhor fazer if (minValue === 0 || maxValue === 0). O operador ! faz conversões nem sempre óbvias, e para validações mais precisas é melhor detalhar bem o que quer (converter para o tipo apropriado e testar os valores específicos, etc). E ainda tem o fato de Number retornar zero se passar uma string vazia ou só contendo espaços (ou seja, não dá para diferenciar quando foi digitado zero, ou nada, ou espaços).

Não duplique perguntas. Se precisar revisar algo faça na pergunta original clicando no link "editar" que fica abaixo da pergunta original. Comentários devem ser feitos na pergunta original, também.
